# Usage of Razor expressions with or without string quotes

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

Regarding Razor expression usage (ASP.Net) cases, there are two cases  commonly met:

```
<div title="@MyClass.Test"></div>
```

and

```
<div title=@MyClass.Test></div>
```

As they both seem to work the same on 
Razor 2.0, I would like to know if there are any differences, especially in corner cases (null/malfored values etc).

Eventually I would also like to know which is best as a practice to follow. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The rules for HTML attributes can be found [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/syntax.html#elements-attributes). The quotes are usually optional, but if there is a space in the value of `MyClass.Test` then you'll need them.

I would say best practice is to include them as it doesn't hurt and will save you problems if there are spaces in the value.